# Proper way to setup AWSAppSyncClient, Apollo & React

Tags: graphql, react-apollo, apollo-client, aws-appsync

I've been having issues getting started with React, Apollo, and AWS-AppSync. I can't resolve this error message:

```
TypeError: this.currentObservable.query.getCurrentResult is not a function
```

I'm using the updated packages of @apollo/react-hooks and aws-appsync.

My current setup looks like this.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';

import config from './aws-exports';
import AWSAppSyncClient from 'aws-appsync';
import { ApolloProvider } from '@apollo/react-hooks';

const client = new AWSAppSyncClient({
    url: config.aws_appsync_graphqlEndpoint,
    region: config.aws_appsync_region,
    auth: {
        type: config.aws_appsync_authenticationType,
        apiKey: config.aws_appsync_apiKey
    }
});

ReactDOM.render(
    <ApolloProvider client={client}>
        <React.StrictMode>
            <App />
        </React.StrictMode>
    </ApolloProvider>,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

And I have a function that makes a query that looks like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import { useQuery } from '@apollo/react-hooks';
import gql from 'graphql-tag';

const Flavors = () => {

    const GET_FLAVORS = gql`
        query listAll {
            items {
                name,
                image
            }
        }
    `;

    const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(GET_FLAVORS);

    if(loading) return <p>loading...</p>
    if(error) return <p>Something went wrong...</p>

    return (
        <div>
        {
            data.listIceCreamTypes.items.map(type => {
                return <div key={type.name}>
                    <img src={type.image} alt={type.name} />
                    <h1>{type.name}</h1>
                </div>
            })
        }
        </div>
    )
}

export default Flavors;
```

I've gone through various solutions described in https://github.com/apollographql/react-apollo/issues/3148 such as adding:

```
"resolutions": {
    "apollo-client": "2.6.3"
 }
```

to package.json. Then re-running npm install and restarting the server.

Nothing seems to solve my issues.

Edit** Here's a repo to reproduce the problem: https://github.com/Rynebenson/IceCreamQL

Answer (score 11):

I already answered this on other related question here on stackoverflow..

As mentioned in other answer the problem is because aws-appsync is relying in an previous version apollo-client. Using resolutions is not the "cleaner" way to solve this problem as you're fixing a dependency version which is not fully compatible with this library.

I strongly recommend you to create a custom apollo client for AWS AppSync this way:

```
import { ApolloProvider } from '@apollo/react-hooks';
import { ApolloLink } from 'apollo-link';
import { createAuthLink } from 'aws-appsync-auth-link';
import { createHttpLink } from 'apollo-link-http';
import { AppSyncConfig } from './aws-exports';
import ApolloClient from 'apollo-client';

const url = AppSyncConfig.graphqlEndpoint;
const region = AppSyncConfig.region;
const auth = {
  type: AppSyncConfig.authenticationType,
  apiKey: AppSyncConfig.apiKey
};
const link = ApolloLink.from([
   createAuthLink({ url, region, auth }), 
   createHttpLink({ uri: url })
]);
const client = new ApolloClient({
  link,
  cache: new InMemoryCache()
});

const WithProvider = () => (
  <ApolloProvider client={client}>
    <App />
  </ApolloProvider>
)

export default WithProvider
```

I also created a more detailed post on [medium](https://medium.com/@guillac124/create-your-custom-apollo-client-for-aws-appsync-to-use-hooks-2d5cbce29db5)

Comment: I saw your post on given link but using the same code in my project. Is there anything else to be done to get it working in production mode?

Answer (score 0):

Wanted to post my experience that is a more recent. The accepted answer is still correct. `aws-appsync` uses outdated packages which conflict with the newest versions of the apollo client.

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

// Apollo Settings
import { ApolloClient, ApolloProvider, InMemoryCache } from '@apollo/client';
import { ApolloLink } from 'apollo-link';

// AppSync
import { Auth } from 'aws-amplify';
import { createAuthLink } from 'aws-appsync-auth-link';
import { createHttpLink } from 'apollo-link-http';
import awsconfig from 'assets/lib/aws-exports';

// jwtToken is used for AWS Cognito.
const client = new ApolloClient({
  link: ApolloLink.from([
    createAuthLink({
      url: awsconfig.aws_appsync_graphqlEndpoint,
      region: awsconfig.aws_appsync_region,
      auth: {
        type: awsconfig.aws_appsync_authenticationType,
        apiKey: awsconfig.aws_appsync_apiKey,
        jwtToken: async () => (await Auth.currentSession()).getAccessToken().getJwtToken(),
      },
    }),
    createHttpLink({ uri: awsconfig.aws_appsync_graphqlEndpoint }),
  ]),
  cache: new InMemoryCache(),
});

const withApollo = ({ children}) => {
  return <ApolloProvider client={client}><App /></ApolloProvider>;
};

withApollo.propTypes = {
  children: PropTypes.object,
  authData: PropTypes.object,
};

export default withApollo;
```

Package.json

```
"@apollo/client": "^3.3.15",
"@apollo/react-hooks": "^4.0.0",
"apollo-link": "^1.2.14",
"apollo-link-http": "^1.5.17",
"aws-amplify": "^3.3.27",
"aws-amplify-react-native": "^4.3.2",
"aws-appsync-auth-link": "^3.0.4",
```

Comment: Hi there. I have implemented the same code but it only seem to be working for development mode. Is there any other configuration for production that needs to be done?

Answer (score 0):

You must initialize appsync like the following method.

```
const graphqlClient = new appsync.AWSAppSyncClient({
url: graphqlEndpoint,
region: process.env.AWS_REGION,
auth: {
    type: 'AWS_IAM',
    credentials: {
        accessKeyId: process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
        secretAccessKey: process.env.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
        sessionToken: process.env.AWS_SESSION_TOKEN
    }
},
disableOffline: true
```

});