# Cannot connect apollo client to aws appsync

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, apollo-client, aws-appsync

I have a web app using aws appsync as backend and react + apollo client (v3) as front end. But when I try connecting apollo client to appsync, I get an error message from the library:

> ./node_modules/aws-appsync-react/lib/offline-helpers.js
>
> Module not found: Can't resolve 'react-apollo' in '/Users/mypath/web/node_modules/aws-appsync-react/lib'

Here's the config for the client:

```
import AWSAppSyncClient from "aws-appsync";
import AppSyncConfig from "./aws-exports";

export const apolloClient = new AWSAppSyncClient({
  url: AppSyncConfig.aws_appsync_graphqlEndpoint,
  region: AppSyncConfig.aws_appsync_region,
  auth: {
    type: AppSyncConfig.aws_appsync_authenticationType,
    apiKey: AppSyncConfig.aws_appsync_apiKey,
  },
});
```

And the in my `App.ts`:

```
import { ApolloProvider } from "@apollo/client";
import { Rehydrated } from "aws-appsync-react";
import { apolloClient } from "./apollo";

...
<ApolloProvider client={apolloClient}>
  <Rehydrated>
      <MyApp />
  </Rehydrated>
</ApolloProvider>
```

Looks like a compatibility issue?

I'm using `"@apollo/client": "^3.1.3", "aws-appsync": "^4.0.0","aws-appsync-react": "^4.0.0",`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a compatibility issue. Current version of `aws-appsync` doesn't support `apollo-client` v3, see this thread for progress:
https://github.com/awslabs/aws-mobile-appsync-sdk-js/issues/448

Best workaround is this: [Proper way to setup AWSAppSyncClient, Apollo & React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60804372/proper-way-to-setup-awsappsyncclient-apollo-react)

Note the workaround does use two deprecated libraries but can be slightly improved as:

```
import { ApolloClient, ApolloLink, InMemoryCache } from "@apollo/client";
import { createAuthLink } from "aws-appsync-auth-link";
import { createHttpLink } from "apollo-link-http";
import AppSyncConfig from "./aws-exports";

const url = AppSyncConfig.aws_appsync_graphqlEndpoint;
const region = AppSyncConfig.aws_project_region;
const auth = {
  type: AppSyncConfig.aws_appsync_authenticationType,
  apiKey: AppSyncConfig.aws_appsync_apiKey,
};
const link = ApolloLink.from([
  // @ts-ignore
  createAuthLink({ url, region, auth }),
  // @ts-ignore
  createHttpLink({ uri: url }),
]);
const client = new ApolloClient({
  link,
  cache: new InMemoryCache(),
});

export default client;
```

Comment: Hi there. I have implemented the same code but it only seem to be working for development mode. Is there any other configuration for production that needs to be done?